# U-substitution in disguise (notation) --- what is $d(2x+1)$?

Tags: calculus, notation

I would like to know if there is a name for this notation here, which I've seen many times.

$$\int \frac{1}{2x+1} \ dx= \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{2x+1} \ d(2x+1)=\frac{1}{2} \ln|2x+1|+c$$

Thanks

Comment: Which notation in particular?

Comment: The $\ d(2x+1)$ is what I want to know about.

Comment: It's just a differential. More often (for ease of presentation or computation) we'd give it another name, e.g., $u$, and write $\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{du}{u}$.

Comment: One of my profs uses that notation all the time. It really took me awhile to get used to it. I have to do the regular u-substitution and then (in this case) substitute $du=d(2x+1)$ into the equation if i want it to look like that. I don't know that there is a certain name for it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two more examples of this notation:

$$ I_1 = \int \cos x \,\mathrm{d}x = \int \mathrm{d}(\sin x) = \sin x + c $$

$$ I_2 = \int xe^{-x^2} \,\mathrm{d}x = -\frac{1}{2}\int \mathrm{d}(e^{-x^2}) = -\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2}+k$$

It's essentially saying that:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}(\sin x + c)}{dx} = \cos x $$
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}\left(-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2}+k\right)}{\mathrm{d}x} = xe^{-x^2} $$

So it's a "u-substitution" or "t-substitution" if you substitute $ u = \sin x + c$ or $t = -\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2}+k$ and differentiate. Over here you're just using the expression directly because it represents the same thing. It's a little abusive notation of the differential as I see it.